# codeigniter hmvc extension routing error

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I have a strange error with CodeIgniter using HMVC extension. On localhost it runs fine and on a Linux server I get this error `Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.` even tho everything is configured fine. I have done some core CodeIgniter debugging and found that fetch_directory() base method is returning 
`../modules/{controller}/{action} instead of modules/{controller}/{action}`
Anyone else had this problem? what is the solution to fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

I had this identical problem, also using HMVC architecture. Here is my solution for the benefit of others.

In my case, it turned out to be the fact that I had removed the */application/controllers/* directory. Because this directory is always empty, being replaced by the controllers in the individual modules, I (wrongly) thought it would be fine to 'tidy it up'.

Actually, the MX routing references it in the path it creates for the router to find the modules;

```
APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->fetch_directory().$RTR->fetch_class().'.php'
```

So the ../ part is correct. I suspect your local environment is Windows (like mine) which managed to work around this broken path somehow, in a way that Linux is unable to.

So the simple fix for this scenario is... put the **/application/controllers/** directory back.

Comment: thanks this was the problem for me and i added controllers folder and solved

Comment: i am getting the same problem cant able to solve ,please help

Answer (score 0):

It could be several things:

1. ) Check your config file and see what the config['base_url'] is set to, it could be a mismatch between your development environment (e.g. "localhost") and your production environment (e.g. "http://www.example.com")
2. ) Double check your routes.php file and make sure that the default page controller is set to the controller.  Then triple check to make sure the spellings match!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and change `$this->class` and `$this->method` to `$class` and `$method` respectively in `set_class` and `set_method` function in `My_Router class` like,

```
public function set_class($class) {
    $this->class = str_replace('-', '_',$class).$this->config->item('controller_suffix');
                                   //---^ remove $this from here
}

public function set_method($method) {
    $this->method = str_replace('-', '_',$method);
                                    //---^ remove $this from here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too solved with charliefortune's answer. Thanks.
Be aware that if you recreate from .rar or upload to certain servers, empty folders might be deleted. Therefore, you should maybe add some files to the "controllers" folder.